# Retrofit GET request with JSON parameters

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2

I'm trying to GET from a Parse Server with Retrofit my custom object.

The http request would be:

```
https://MY.SERVER./1/classes/Fiestas?where={"Epoca":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"Epocas","objectId":"myObjectId"}}
```

So I have this interface:

```
@GET("Fiestas?where={\"Epoca\":{\"__type\":\"Pointer\",\"className\":\"Epocas\",\"objectId\":\"{epoca_id}\"}}")
fun getFiestaByEpocaId(@Path("epoca_id") epoca_id: String): Deferred<JSONResponse>
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL query string "where={"Epoca":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"Epocas","objectId":"{epoca_id}"}}" must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query.
    for method FiestaApi.getFiestaByEpocaId
```

Some one knows any solution to send a JSON inside GET retrofit request in kotlin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
@GET("Fiestas")
fun getFiestaByEpocaId(
    @Query("where") jsonString: String
): Call<JSONObject>
```

Your json object is:

```
val jsonString = "{\"__type\":\"Pointer\",\"className\":\"Epocas\",\"objectId\":\"{epoca_id}\"}}"
```

And call jsonString.replace("\","") before request method